# How use font for create a border

Tags: html, css

There is the possibility to use a font for creating a border?

I want to build something like this

```
*****************
* hello world   *
* some text     *
*****************
```

instead have a normal border I need to use * is possible with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the css 'border-image' property with an image of some asterisks forming a square.

Something along the lines of [the examples here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_border_images.asp).